# What's the difference between demand elasticity and demand volatility?

Tags: volatility, elasticity

What's the difference between demand elasticity and demand volatility?

Demand elasticity: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/demand-elasticity.asp

Demand volatility: https://www.sdcexec.com/home/article/10289792/supply-chain-strategies-to-manage-volatile-demand

Thanks!

Comment: Volatile demand is demand which changes a lot (the opposite would be constant demand). Elastic demand is demand which changes a lor *in response to change in price (or change in income)*. Something could have low elasticity and still change a lot because of **other reasons** for example due to random factors or factors other than price/income.